# How to change value of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I find to find some words in dictionary and replace the with another words . wrote the following code, but there is no change in the output. I don't know how can I change the output?

```
for elem in output:
    for el in elem ['tags']:
        if el== 'datamining':
            el='data mining'
        elif el== 'data science':
            el='data mining'

print(output)
```

new words

```
d = {
    'datamining': 'data mining',
    'data science': 'data mining',
}
```

dictionary

```
[{'title': 'title1',
  'tags': ['datamining', 'data science',
   'test',
   'data mining',
   'test1']},
 {'title': 'title2',
  'tags': ['title2',
   'datamining']
 }
  ]
```

expected dictionary

```
[{'title': 'title1',
  'tags': ['data mining', 'data mining',
   'test',
   'data mining',
   'test1']},
 {'title': 'title2',
  'tags': ['title2',
   'data mining']
 }
  ]
```

Comment: `el='data mining'` doesn't do anything useful. You have to modify using `elem['tags']` and an index.

Comment: `el` is a local loop variable, not related to any other variable. if you decide to modify it, it only affects it within the scope of the for loop (and outside the loop, if you decide to access it once the loop concludes)

Comment: also, please format your code properly. `\u20` is an invalid literal in a string, and `output` is unfortunately named - its actually used as an input object it looks like.

Comment: @rv.kvetch How can I remove \u20 from all my data?

Comment: not from all your data, only from the sample data.

Comment: @user12217822 I suggested an edit, take a look.

Comment: thank you so much, but some of my data has unwanted char like \u20 how can I fix them?

Comment: hmm, I'm not entirely sure. that might be worth another question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
for i, elem in enumerate(output):
    for j, el in enumerate(elem ['tags']):
        if 'datamining' in el:
            output[i]['tags'][j]='data mining'
        elif 'data science' in el:
            output[i]['tags'][j]='data mining'
```

To eliminate the \u20:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(output):
    for j, el in enumerate(elem ['tags']):
        output[i]['tags'][j] = output[i]['tags'][j].replace("\\u20", "")
        output[i]['tags'][j] = output[i]['tags'][j].replace('datamining', 'data mining')
        output[i]['tags'][j] = output[i]['tags'][j].replace('data science', 'data mining')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for elem in output:
    for idx, el in enumerate(elem['tags'][:]):
        if el == 'datamining':
            elem['tags'][idx] = 'data mining'
        elif el == 'data science':
            elem['tags'][idx] = 'data mining'
```

since you cant change an object that you are iterating we make a shallow copy with the slice syntax `[:]`

Comment: This is false, you can actually mutate elements while iterating over the list. It's only operations that affect the list size that you can't do while iterating over it.

Comment: @rv.kvetch How can I fix it?

Comment: same as above, but you can remove the `[:]`. the answer is wrong, you technically don't need it.